# How to store file data lines and pass it method to calculate into letters and print letter grades in another file?

Tags: java, loops, oop, multidimensional-array, object-oriented-database

class.txt

- Reena Sam, 100, 90, 80, 100,
- Donna D. Bartolome, 90, 90, 100, 100,
- Chris Tui, 100, 90, 100, 70,

I'm new to java and I'm trying to figure out
how to store file data lines  to calculate into letters and print letter grades in another file?

I'm trying to look into storing into multiple objects or ArrayLists…

like this:

- Reena Sam:           A
- Donna D. Bartolome:  B
- Chris Tui:           C

Below is my current progress towards this, but I got stuck in trying to store the data. pls help...

```js
...
class gradeMaker{
 private Scanner readFile;
    private String[] argument;
    private ArrayList<String> list; 
    private String finalGrade ="";
 
 gradeMaker(String [] arg) {
  argument = arg;
 }

 void readStudentScores() {
 
  File file = new File(argument[0]);
  if (!file.exists()) {
   System.out.println("Input file" + argument[0] + "does not exist");
   System.exit(2);
  }
  
  try{  // Create a Scanner for the file
     readFile = new Scanner(file);
     ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
   
        // Read data from a file
     System.out.println("Read data from a file");
     while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
      String temp = readFile.nextLine();   
           
      //list.add(new Student ()); //Stores Student student1 = new Student(Name2, 20, 28, 60,) 
                                   //Stores Student student2 = new Student(Name2, 20, 28, 60,)      
                                  
      
      System.out.println(temp);
      
      //String[] studentInfo = line.split(",");
      
      
    }
     
     Collections.sort(list);
     for (int i = list.size(); i >= 0; i++)
         System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
     System.out.println(list.toString());
     // System.out.println();
     
     
  }catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Error Reading from file:" + file + e.getMessage());
  
  }
  
  
  }
   

 void computeGrade() {
  
  int Q1 = quiz1;
  int Q2 = quiz2;
  int M1 = mid;
  int FN = finals;
   
  int finalScore = (Q1 * .20 + Q2 * .20 + M1 * .25 + FN * .35);
  if (finalScore >= .9) 
   finalGrade = "A";
  else if (finalScore >= .8 && finalScore <= .89 )
   finalGrade = "B";
  else if (finalScore >= .7 && finalScore <= .79 )
   finalGrade = "C";
  else if (finalScore >= .6 && finalScore <= .69 )
   finalGrade = "D";
  else if (finalScore <= .59 )
   finalGrade = "F";
  //}    
 }

 void Grades() {
  File outputFile = new File(argument[1]);
  try {
   PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
   
   while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
   output.println(finalGrade);
   }
  
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }  
 }

                   
}
```

Comment: That' s a lot of code for a relatively simple requirement. Do you really need 7 constructors in your `Student` class? Why does gradeMaker extends Student?

Comment: I'm new to java, so any advice on how to improve my code is welcome. I think I only really need the constructor with all the items in the data. Shall I delete the others?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things here. First, I see you have a System print set to catch unknown errors on your collections sort. printStackTrace will be more useful there.

Also your PrintWriter is returning just a grade. To get the output you want, you really want to return a constructor with a concatenated string. You can do this by making an object of your class that handles the arguments you need to return. Something like:

```
String finalGrade = f.toString();

public gradeMarker(String name, String finalGrade) {
     this.name = name;
     this.finalGrade = finalGrade;
 }
```

You have final grade as an integer (f), but personally I find it easier to read/write data as strings. You can follow this up with your getter and setter methods, and then put a final method that returns the output you want. Something like

```
public String toString() {
    return name + "," + finalGrade;
}
```

You can then put your results in a list and write it to the file using a for each loop

```
List<gradeMaker> grade = FileReader(//your file)
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(//your file)
for (gradeMaker x : grade) {
    output.println(x);
}
```

That'll print each line, and since it's for each will only go long as an object exists to print. Hope all of that helps!

Comment: @Zack do you mind if you could show me an example of your preferred way?

Comment: Sure! Rather than bog down this thread though, I'll share my Github repository. Keep in mind this project uses a bunch of external packages to run, but you should be able to use your IDE of choice to read my class files and see how I imported my data into arrays. https://github.com/zrr817/JavaNebula

Answer (score 1):

Here is fully working example as starting point. If you are using Java 7 or above you can improve it by using `java.nio.file`, which is a way to work with files up todays standards, instead of `java.io.File`. You could also consider using java 8 `streams` to make mapping a line to an object cleaner and more readable.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MarksToGrades {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String inputFile = "C:\\Users\\Eritrean\\Desktop\\marks.txt";
        List<Student> students = readFileAndGetStudents(inputFile);
        String outputFile = "C:\\Users\\Eritrean\\Desktop\\grades.txt";
        writeStudentsDataToFile(students,outputFile);
    }

    static List<Student> readFileAndGetStudents(String inputFileName){
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        try(FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(inputFileName));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);){

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                students.add(new Student(line));
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
        return students;
    }
    static void writeStudentsDataToFile(List<Student> students, String outputFileName){
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFileName);
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {
            for(Student stud : students){
                System.out.println(stud.toString());
                bw.write(stud.toString());
                bw.newLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static class Student{
        String name;
        int quiz1;
        int quiz2;
        int  mid1;;
        int finals;
        double total;
        char grade;
        // getter & setter omitted as they are not important for this task. if necessary, you can add them

        public Student(String line) {
            String[] data = line.split(",");
            this.name   = data[0];
            this.quiz1  = Integer.parseInt(data[1].trim());
            this.quiz2  = Integer.parseInt(data[2].trim());
            this.mid1   = Integer.parseInt(data[3].trim());
            this.finals = Integer.parseInt(data[4].trim());
            this.total = calculateTotal (quiz1,quiz2,mid1,finals);
            this.grade = getGrade(total);
        }

        private double calculateTotal(int quiz1, int quiz2, int mid1, int finals) {
            return quiz1 * .20 + quiz2 * .20 + mid1 * .25 + finals * .35;
        }

        private char getGrade(double total) {
            if (total >= 90) 
                return 'A';
            else if (total >= 80)
                return 'B';
            else if (total >= 70)
                return 'C';
            else if (total >= 60)
                return 'D';
            else 
                return 'F';
        } 

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return  name + ": " + grade ;
        }        
    }
}
```